# How come my BeautifulSoup object doesn't contain the text attribute that my webpage does?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python 2.7 and turning a requests.content into a BeautifulSoup object. When I use the developer tools to view a div, there is text within the div.  When I use BeautifulSoup to return the div, there is not text in the div.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from string import punctuation
from requests import get

roster = pd.read_csv(#file w/ player names)

name_corrections = {

    'matt-dellavedova' : 'matthew-dellavedova',
    'marcelinho-huertas' : 'marcelo-huertas',
    'derrick-jones' : 'derrick-jones-jr',
    'john-lucas' : 'john-lucas-iii',
    'james-mcadoo' : 'james-michael-mcadoo',
    'raulzinho-neto' : 'raul-neto',
    'otto-porter' : 'otto-porter-jr',
    'glenn-robinson' : 'glenn-robinson-iii',
    'domas-sabonis' : 'domantas-sabonis',
    'lou-williams' : 'louis-williams',
    'joe-young' : 'joseph-young',

   }

url = 'http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/'

def remove_punctuation(s):
   s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in ".,'"])
   return s

def process_id(roster):

    roster['538id'] = roster['Player'].apply(remove_punctuation)

    roster['538id'] = roster['538id'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ",     "-"))

    roster['538id'] = roster['538id'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())

    roster['538id'].replace(name_corrections, inplace=True)


process_id(roster)

page = get(xurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

soup.findAll('div', class_='market-value')
```

this returns:

[return from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChlUK.png)

[view from developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNJ0r.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue people have when scraping webpages.

So simply speaking, **the data you want is NOT in that page**(http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/) after all, that's why you got nothing from your code, and **what you've seen in developer tools is the result of a fully rendered webpage**, therefore all data is ready.

The actual data you want is from this url(http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/carmelo/ben-simmons.json), which is requested when the original page is loading and rendering in a webbrowser.

This might be counter-intuitive, [**check out this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007470/python-beautifulsoup-not-scraping-this-url/41009960#41009960) to get a detailed explanation.

Comment: That makes since. And that answer/link was a great read to help me understand what is happening on the front end.

I also was finding that you can use Selenium as a webdriver to help solve some of those render issues.

Thanks for the feedback and answer.

Comment: Glad to know I helped : )